# Custom menu for One page scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using this [onepage scroll plugin](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) and it works great, just that I can't make the custom menu work like the pagination dots even though the markup is exactly similar:

http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/z5ztr1zg/

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#1" data-index="1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2" data-index="2">Section 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="main">
<section>section 1</section>
<section>section 2</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From onepage scroll plugin docs:

> $.fn.moveTo(page_index)
>
> This method allows you to move to the specified page index programatically.
>
> **$(".main").moveTo(3);**

You can use jQuery .click() method:

```
$('#menu a').click(function() {
   $(".main").moveTo($(this).data('index'));
});
```